# Keep keys when shifting associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array (json_encoded):

```
string(86) "{
"1": "1",
"2": "2",
"3": "3",
"4": "4",
"6": "5",
"7": "6"
}"
```

and when using this function :

```
function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
}
```

i get this output :

```
string(56) "[
    "3",
    "1",
    "2",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6"
]"
```

**Can someone explain me why I have lost all my keys?**
thank you !

Comment: What yours input parameters `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: it is not array, rather object with numeric keys (and keys in object are unordered in essence)

Comment: 2, 0 are the inputs @AksenP

Comment: Is there a way I can keep my keys? @IłyaBursov

Comment: @acuz3r to keep keys - don't use splice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine spliced keys and spliced values:

```
function custom_splice(&$ar, $a, $b){
    $out = array_splice($ar, $a, 1);
    array_splice($ar, $b, 0, $out);
}

function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    custom_splice($array, $a, $b);
    custom_splice($keys, $a, $b); 

    $array = array_combine($keys,$array);
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/610P1)**

Comment: i did something similar, i stored the keys in another array then used ````array_combine()````